# 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Whenever I run this along with other sql statements ,it gives an error :

> CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch

However, whenever I execute it alone ( without SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER  in my case it works )

```
   SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;

   create function udfLogin
    (@username nvarchar(100), @password nvarchar(100)) 
    returns int as
    begin
      if exists(select 1 from CUSTOMER where Username = @username and [Password] = @password)
        return 1
      return 0;
    end
```

Comment: Semicolon is missed.

Comment: @Alexander adding a semicolon doesn't start a new batch, it's simply a statement terminator (not a "beginninator" as some people with their `;WITH` statements seem to believe :P). A batch can contain many statements.

Comment: add a `GO`just before the `create function`

Comment: @Larnu , I'm ashamed! The SQL is not my forte :)

Comment: Slightly off topic but you should never store passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to separate each batch of code with GO keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
 GO
   create function udfLogin
    (@username nvarchar(100), @password nvarchar(100)) 
     returns int as
     begin
      if exists(select 1 from CUSTOMER where Username = @username and 
      [Password] = @password)
       return 1
     return 0;
   end
Go
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a batch separator eg Go

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
GO
   create function udfLogin
    (@username nvarchar(100), @password nvarchar(100)) 
    returns int as
    begin
      if exists(select 1 from CUSTOMER where Username = @username and [Password] = @password)
        return 1
      return 0;
    end
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the CREATE FUNCTION statement must be the first statement in a query batch. There should be no other statements before the CREATION FUNCTION statement that would make it not the first statement in a query batch. As the message suggests, to avoid this error the CREATE FUNCTION statement must be the first statement in a query batch.

SQL executes the statement as a query batch.

Rules for Using Batches

The following rules apply to using batches:

> CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE
>   SCHEMA, CREATE TRIGGER, and CREATE VIEW statements cannot be combined
>   with other statements in a batch. 
>   The CREATE statement must start the batch. All other statements that follow in that batch will be interpreted as part of the definition of the first CREATE statement.