# Getting permission error and "function does not exist" error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I am getting an error that Create function must be the first statement in the query batch and that I have to declare @userfirstname and @userlastname. What am I missing?

```
 Drop function if exists dbo.udf_getUserID;

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_getUserID(@userfirstname NVarchar (25), @userlastname NVarchar (50))
RETURNS INT

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @PbUser_id INT;
SELECT  @PbUser_id=PbUser_id
FROM PbUser
WHERE userFirstName =@userfirstname AND
userLastName =@userlastname;

IF @PbUser_id is Null
set @PbUser_id =-1;
return @PbUser_id;
END

SELECT dbo.udf_getUserID('Pace','Wasden');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511648/create-function-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-query-batch)

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION <Function Name> TO '<username>'@'localhost';
```